# Xamarin forms stacklayout returning null

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I tried to get the item on stacklayout into an SQLite Database, but it just won't carry any data with.

```
  private void MainCategory_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var carier = e.SelectedItem as Item;






        var cart_Itemsx = new List<cart_Items>();
        cart_Itemsx.Add(new Models.cart_Items { cartid = 1, Id = carier.itid, image = carier.image, name = carier.title, price = carier.price1, quantity = "1", type = "Wash and Iron" });
        cart_Itemsx.Add(new Models.cart_Items { cartid = 2, Id = carier.itid, image = carier.image, name = carier.title, price = carier.price2, quantity = "1", type = "Iron Only" });
        SubCategory.ItemsSource = cart_Itemsx.ToList();
    }



    private void SubCategory_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbcontet = e.SelectedItem as cart_Items;
        _dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "WashPro.db3");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(_dbPath);
        db.CreateTable<cart_Items>();



        var MaximumPrimaryKey = db.Table<cart_Items>().OrderByDescending(zt => zt.cartid).FirstOrDefault();

        var waltani = new cart_Items()
        {
            cartid = (MaximumPrimaryKey == null ? 1 : MaximumPrimaryKey.cartid + 1),
            Id = dbcontet.Id,
            image = dbcontet.image,
            name = dbcontet.name,
            price = dbcontet.price,
            quantity = dbcontet.quantity,
            type = dbcontet.quantity
        };

        if (MaximumPrimaryKey == null)
        {
            db.Insert(waltani);
        }
        else if (MaximumPrimaryKey != null)
        {
            var MaximumQuantityKey = db.Table<cart_Items>().Where(m => m.cartid.Equals(dbcontet.cartid) && m.type.Equals(dbcontet.type)).FirstOrDefault();

            if (MaximumQuantityKey != null)
            {
               waltani.price = dbcontet.price = 1;
                db.Update(waltani);
            }

        }
        SubCategory.SelectedItem = null;

    }
```

image of the null error I got

[image: image of the null error I got]

I cannot even begin to understand the problem. The way I found around the problem will make my already dirty code way dirtier.

I have the damaging method I tried was using the selected context of the main stack panel to influence the second stack pannel.

I have even made the primary key of the cart_item model null.

Comment: What does this have to do with StackLayout?  Have you stepped through `SubCategory_ItemSelected` in the debugger to verify where they null reference is coming from?

Comment: All. the e.selecteditem as cart_item just returns null

Comment: Is e.selectedItem null?  Or is the cast failing?  If the cast is failing, then what is the actual type of selecteditem?

Comment: The casting is the problem

Comment: if the cast is failing what is the ACTUAL TYPE of SelectedItem and why is it different than they target type you are trying to cast to?  If you've narrowed it down this far the answer should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies at the last line of code.

SubListview.SelectedItem = null;

This somehow makes the casting not see the e.selected items.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selected element is null or database table does not contain any elements you are looking for in query, which is more likely because you are trying to initialize your database on SubCategory_ItemSelected. This is wrong approach.

Try to check if database item exist first.

```
var exist = db.Table<cart_Items>().OrderByDescending(zt => zt.cartid).Any();

if (exist)
{
        var MaximumPrimaryKey = db.Table<cart_Items>().OrderByDescending(zt => zt.cartid).FirstOrDefault();

        var waltani = new cart_Items()
        {
            cartid = (MaximumPrimaryKey == null ? 1 : MaximumPrimaryKey.cartid + 1),
            Id = dbcontet.Id,
            image = dbcontet.image,
            name = dbcontet.name,
            price = dbcontet.price,
            quantity = dbcontet.quantity,
            type = dbcontet.quantity
        };
}
```

Comment: db.CreateTable<cart_Items>();

and

 var MaximumPrimaryKey = db.Table<cart_Items>().OrderByDescending(zt => zt.cartid).FirstOrDefault();

already checks that.

thanks for the help